# Why is my exported fbx not importing with textures?

Tags: mesh, texturing, export, import, .fbx

I made an image mesh on my terrain model. I export this work in fbx format, but when I import it again, only the model comes on and the picture I dress it on does not come. The situation is like the attached pictures. I want my work to look like the first picture when I import it, but I couldn't do it.

Where am I making mistakes?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the images you have provided, you are in "solid preview" mode, what does it look like in "rendered preview"?

Comment: thank you so much. Yes, the image appears, the whole problem was caused by this. Thank you for helping me, my friend. I am just starting to use this program recently.